# Why does my express router not respond to my get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So i have made a simple express app, but i have been trying for several hours to get a response to a simple get request when i visit http://localhost:3000/

This is my app.js

```
// IMPORTS
const express           = require('express')
const mongoose          = require('mongoose')
const customerRouter    = require('./routes/customerRoute.js')
const app               = express()
const PORT              = 3000

// CONNECTION
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Customers', {useUnifiedTopology: true })
mongoose.connection.on('open', () => {console.log('Connected to database.')})

//APP USE ROUTES AND JSON
app.use(express.json)
app.use('/customers',customerRouter)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Home')
})

// APP PORT SET
app.listen(PORT)
console.log('Server started on port 3000')
```

This is my routes file

```
const express = require('express')
const router  = express.Router()

console.log('into the router')

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('GET request')
})


module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `app.use(express.json)` with `app.use(express.json())` and everything will work. You have a mistake in this middleware that parses incoming requests with JSON payloads.

Source: [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in middleware `app.use(express.json())` is a function not a property of the express object.